# vectorize recursive function of numpy array where each element depend on all of the previous ones

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Be a an ndarray, e. g.:

```
a = np.random.randn(Size)
```

Where Size >> 1. Is it possible to define an array b s.t. its i-th element depends on all of the elements of a up to i (excluded or included is not the problem) without a for loop?

```
b[i] = function(a[:i])
```

So if function was simply np.sum(a[:i]) my desired output would be:

```
for i in range(1, Size):
    b[i] = np.sum(a[:i])
```

The only solution I was able to think about was to write the corresponding C code and wrap it, but is there some python native solution to avoid it???

I stress that the sum is a mere ex., I'm lookin for a generalization to arbitrary function that can, howewver, be expressed elementwise by means of numpy mathematical function (np.exp() e.g.)

Comment: So did you try to solve it using Python and was too slow? The code that you posted is O(n^2) and it can be done in O(n) for simple operations like sum and multiplication.

Comment: Many of the `ufunc` have an `accumulate` method.  `np.cumsum` is basically `np.add.accumulate`.  But if you can't use one of those, or some clever combination, and you still want speed, you will need to write some sort of compiled code.  `numba` seems to be preferred tool these days.

Comment: @DaniMesejo that's exactly the point....

Comment: @hpaulj you should post it as answer, I think you correctly catch the point and that reasoning worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Many of the `ufunc` have an `accumulate` method. `np.cumsum` is basically `np.add.accumulate`. But if you can't use one of those, or some clever combination, and you still want speed, you will need to write some sort of compiled code. `numba` seems to be preferred tool these days.

Answer (score -1):

In your example use just numpy cumsum operation https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html.

Edit:

For example, if you create `a = np.ones(10)` with all values equal 1. Then `b = np.cumsum(a)` will contain [1 2 ... 10].

Or as you wanted:

```
for i in range(1, Size):
    b[i] = np.sum(a[:i])
```

Also you can specify axis to apply cumsum to or maybe use `numpy.cumprod` (same operation but with product).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this addresses OP's simple example it doesn't answer OP's actual question, which seems to be that they want to accumulate/reduce with an arbitrary function.

Comment: @ddejohn, if you're being picky about this answer, try writing your own :)  The OP asked me to post my comment as an answer.  It's doesn't add much to this.